# Android Studio MainActivity.java can't find resources

Tags: java, android

I'm basically writing my first hello world in android studio and the java file says that the xml layout file and other resources in the res file don't exist. I took the references to these things from books/tutorials so they should work.

The book said to use

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main.xml);
}
```

But when that didn't work I changed it to     res.layout.activity_main.xml

my project directory looks like this

How do I make it work?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N71sl.png

//EDIT

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUgsm.png

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing res not R.

do something like this: setContentView( R.layout.activity_main);

Leave off the ".xml"

Comment: I referenced it as "setContentView( R.layout.activity_main.xml);" and that didn't work. THEN tried "setContentView( res.layout.activity_main.xml);" ... THEN tried leaving off .xml in both variations and none of this worked. It says "cannot resolve symbol R" when I hover over the red R in  R.layout.activity_main

Comment: Try to restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

update your android studio in stable channel and restart android studio and build the project again .

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the concept of the R class in android.
The R class is auto generated every time you build your project and cannot be modified.
This class contains a map of all the projects assets. Every time you created or import a resource, set a dimension, a string,  create a layout, add or change id etc. the R file is changed in the background.

So if you want to access a resource you simply call it using the R class.
For example:

```
layout: R.layout.activity_main
string: R.string.hello_world
id:     R.id.et_main_helloWorld
```

And so on.
More info can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html).
Make sure you also check **Providing Resources** and **Accessing Resources** for a better understanding.

Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I started a new project and added in everything piece by piece, I had put a mp3 file in the values directory which was messing up the R file.